# Javascript + GreenSock - tweens not functioning correctly after on/off button click

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am having some basic Javascript and GreenSock issues with some playing card animations and a button. I am trying to get the array of playing cards in the test to...

1. Shift down on hover -*done*
2. flip the card to display the other side on click, then once mouse has left card face it should flip back -*done*
3. Implement on/off button to switch between show all card faces/show all card backs - *done*

**Now here are where issues arise once they're all done in one session...**

Once the on/off button has been clicked even once, the user gets stuck in a loop where you can then only use the on/off button to rotate the cards.

I think this is happening because the on/off button is active so it is only using the *off* or *else* section of the animation, the problem is I just can't wrap my head around how I would approach this to solve the issue and enable normal function after revealing all cards. I thought about using a different method instead of essentially a true/false to control but I'm struggling with coming up with any desired results.

A secondary issue is that once all card faces are being shown I would like it to disregard the previous hover flip animation and keep the faces showing until a card has been clicked or the button has flipped them all, but this is unimportant in comparison to the first problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated as this has been puzzling me since yesterday!

**http://codepen.io/Nexus1234/pen/oIgDi**

```
TweenLite.set(".cardWrapper", {perspective:800});
TweenLite.set(".card", {transformStyle:"preserve-3d"});
TweenLite.set(".back", {rotationY:-180});
TweenLite.set([".back", ".front"], {backfaceVisibility:"hidden"});

function onoff(){
  currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;
  if(currentvalue == "Off"){
    document.getElementById("onoff").value="On",
    $(".cardflip").click(
    function () {
    TweenLite.to($(this).find(".card"), 2.0, {scale:1, rotationY:20, ease:Power4.easeOut}); 
  }); 
  }else{ 
    document.getElementById("onoff").value="Off",
     $(".cardflip").click(
     function () { 
     TweenLite.to($(this).find(".card"), 1.0, {scale:1.2, rotationY:180, ease:Strong.easeOut});
  });
  }
}

  $(".cardWrapper").hover(
  function() {
    TweenLite.to($(this).find(".card"), 4.0, {rotationY:20, scale:1,  ease:Power4.easeOut}); 
    TweenLite.to($(this).find(".shine"), 0, {scale:1, rotationY:0, ease:Strong.easeOut
        });   
  });

  $(".cardWrapper").click(
  function() {
    TweenLite.to($(this).find(".card"), 1.0, {scale:1.2, rotationY:180, ease:Strong.easeOut
         });
     TweenLite.to($(this).find(".shine"), 0, {scale:0, rotationY:180, ease:Strong.easeOut
         });
  });

TweenMax.staggerTo($(".card"), 0.45, {rotationY:20}, 0.1);
TweenMax.staggerTo(".shine", 0.75, {x:0}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're onoff function binds a click event to the card container for absolutely no perceivable reason. Thus, when returning from the all-cards-flipped view, the single-card-flip animations are competing with the animations bound to whatever the switch value was when you last flipped all the cards backed.

I write my tween code differently, but the following adaptation works for me:

```
var switchVal = document.getElementById('onoff').value,
    cardFlip = $('.cardflip'),
    allCards = cardFlip.find('.card');

var switchProps = {
    off: {scale:1, rotationY:20, ease:Power4.easeout },
    on: {scale:1.2, rotationY:180, ease:Strong.easeout }
};

function onoff(){
    if (switchVal === 'Off') {
        switchVal = "On";
        TweenLite.to(allCards, 2.0, switchProps.off);
    } else {
        switchVal = "Off";
        TweenLite.to(allCards, 1.0, switchProps.on);
    }
};
```

If you do find some purpose for needing to maintain that click event, just make sure to unbind it when returning from the all-card-flipped view.

**Also, not a root of your problem, but should note that your CP's tweens mix both TweenLite & TweenMax.

Comment: You are a good man! Thank you. This has been on hold since this was posted a few months back so I appreciate the help. On another note, when all the cards are showing face up after clicking the show all button, is there a better way of writing my singular hover and click function so when you hovered over the individual cards it didn't flip them back?